# Eclipse and Project Explorer with RTC multiple repositories

Tags: eclipse, rtc

Is it possible to have multiple versions of project explorer, or be able to create multiple folders to hold RTC repository folders?

I have multiple RTC repositories that i will need to hop back and forth between the two, and it would be easiest if I could have both of those repositories loaded into separate folders in the project Explorer(June/July/Aug/etc).

Currently what I have to do is, if i have repo1 loaded into project explorer, but need something from repo2, i would have to remove the project from repo1, reload it from repo2, so i could see it in the project explorer and work with it there.

Is there any other way to do this other than create multiple workspaces?

Comment: Did you try and, as a workaround, share components between projects, instead of trying to load multiple projects? You can add a component from project1 onto a stream of project2.